# error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `unix` in `os` --> geyser-plugin-manager\src\geyser_plugin_manager.rs:395:43

Tags: solana-program

I am trying to set up Solana to Windows 10, when I run the "cargo test" command after build, I get an error message like:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `unix` in `os`
   --> geyser-plugin-manager\src\geyser_plugin_manager.rs:395:43
    |
395 |             Library::from(libloading::os::unix::Library::this()),
    |                                           ^^^^ could not find `unix` in `os`
    |
help: consider importing one of these items
    |
380 +     use crate::geyser_plugin_manager::Library;
    |
380 +     use libloading::Library;
    |
380 +     use libloading::os::windows::Library;
    |
help: if you import `Library`, refer to it directly
    |
395 -             Library::from(libloading::os::unix::Library::this()),
395 +             Library::from(Library::this()),
    |
```

This part is in **geyser_plugin_manager.rs** file, the related code part:

```
pub(super) fn dummy_plugin_and_library<P: GeyserPlugin>(
        plugin: P,
        config_path: &'static str,
    ) -> (Box<dyn GeyserPlugin>, Library, &'static str) {
        (
            Box::new(plugin),
            Library::from(libloading::os::windows::Library::this()),
            config_path,
        )
    }
```

When I changed this line with

```
Library::from(Library::this()),
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `this` found for struct `libloading::Library` in the current scope
   --> geyser-plugin-manager\src\geyser_plugin_manager.rs:395:36
    |
395 |             Library::from(Library::this()),
    |                                    ^^^^ function or associated item not found in `Library`
```

In addition, When I try

```
Library::from(libloading::os::windows::Library::this()),
```

I get this error:

```
Type mismatch 
[E0308] expected `libloading::os::windows::Library`, but found `Result<libloading::os::windows::Library, Error>`
```

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `this()` is inconsistent between unix and windows. On unix, it returns `Library`, but on windows, it returns `Result<Library, Error>`. If you want to fix the last bug you're seeing, you can simply do:

```
Library::from(libloading::os::windows::Library::this().unwrap()),
```

But to be honest, I'm not sure that geyser will work on Windows. I hope I'm wrong on that!

- Docs for unix: https://docs.rs/libloading/latest/libloading/os/unix/struct.Library.html#method.this
- Docs for windows: https://docs.rs/libloading/latest/libloading/os/windows/struct.Library.html#method.this